# UINavigationController push viewcontroller with hidden navigationbar

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

I have a `UINavigationController` and its `navigationBar` hides if the user scrolls (done with `UIScrollViewDelegate`, not with pan gesture).

But when I push a a new `viewController` onto the stack, the new controller's view's origin y is at 64px and not where the old `topViewController`'s y was (which is 21px).

How can I make the push, so that the new controller appears at the same position as the old one was?

The only place that updating the view's frame was successful was in `viewDidAppear`, but that's to late, because the user can see a black space on the top for a second.

*Updated:*

It seams like it has to be done between `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`, but I can not find reasonable method to do this.

Tried to alter the `UINavigationController`'s view (currently I'm just moving it's `navigationBar`), but that messes up the layout.

*Update again:*

Some more info, because none of the answers and comments helped. The navigationcontroller is instantiated from storyboard. It's a custom `UINavigationController`, which hides the `navigationBar` on it's `topViewController`'s `scrollView` scrolling (nothing else is overwritten).

The first `topViewController` (from which the push is started) is a `UIViewController` with 2 container view (one if logged in, other if not). The second `topViewController` (the one which is pushed onto the stack) is a `UIViewController` with a full screen `UIWebView`.

Everything is coming from the storyboard. All the `Extended Edges` checkboxes are off for every `viewController` and all the `navigationBars` are opaque. `AutoLayout` is used everywhere and (I think setup right).

Comment: Check whether your new ViewController's and the ViewController from which you are pushing has same navigationBar property. `navigationBar.translucent` and `navigationBar.opaque`
These properties changes the originY of the ViewController's view.

Comment: Thanks, but both of them are opaque.

Comment: In my app what I have done is, used a `bool` property to access whether the navigationBar was hidden in the viewController when pushing a new VC. In the viewWillAppear, I check if the navBar was hidden. If yes, I set it's frame. I'm not sure whether it's best practice, but it does the job.

Comment: This is what I'm trying to do, but setting in `viewWillAppear` doesn't work. When it gets to `viewDidAppear` the frame is back to the original. Something is altering the frame between `viewWillAppear` and `viewDidAppear`.

Answer (score 0):

--Edited--

change your frame in `viewWillAppear`method

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 21, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
}
```

or setFrame of your newController before to be pushed.

```
NewController *newC = [NewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewController" bundle:nil];
[newC.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 21, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

[self.navigationController pushViewController:newC animated: YES];
```